# <JSP> Stuck on Onclick mehot d with Ajax

Tags: ajax, jsp

I have a code as following;

**JSP**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  fnSelGrp = function(year) 
  $('#name').val(nm); 
  }; 
</script> 

<table id = "One"> 
<tr> <td>onclick="fnSelGrp('${result.name}')">${result.name}</td> </tr>
</table>

<table id="Two">
<tr> <td> "HELLO" </td> </tr>
</table>
```

When I click on 'name', I want the table 'Two' to be disappeared and replace it with other JSP page, using AJAX.

It seems I should give 'fnSelGrp' an ID to make onClick function.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Install and use fire bug this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using jquery, so ensure that your jquery libraries are included before the `<script>` tag.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The code

```
$('#name').val(nm);
```

means set the value of the element with the ID `name` with nm

You do not have a element with the ID `name`